# Get amount of screen home in Android except the offsetChange function

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, samsung-touchwiz

I know about `offsetChange` function, but it doesn't work on such devices as Galaxy S4. I think it happens because of `TouchWiz` wrapper. So I need to find out another way to determine count of home screens.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please explain what "count of home screens" means.

Comment: Android has main screen like desktop. There are several home screens, you can switch between them. So I need to get amount of them.

Answer (score -1):

> Android has main screen like desktop.

Android has a home screen. Whether it is "like desktop" or not depends upon the device and user.

> There are several home screens, you can switch between them

It is unclear what you mean by this.

You might mean "an Android device can have multiple applications installed that each offer to be a home screen, and the user can choose which of those applications to use". In that case, creating an `Intent` for `ACTION_MAIN` and `CATEGORY_HOME`, then passing that to `queryIntentActivities()` on PackageManager, should give you the list of possible home screen implementations.

You might mean "all Android home screens offer some sort of swiping option to move to different portions of space". *Some* home screens offer this, and there is no standard way to find out. There is no requirement that a home screen offer the capability of swiping this way, let alone a requirement to supply an API for third-party apps to find out details about them.

Comment: @Ares: That is covered in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: In your opinion there is no simple way to determine this. Right?

Comment: @Ares: There is no simple way to determine this. In general, there is no way **at all** to determine this, though certain home screens may offer up solutions.